# Is $K \otimes_k L$ a semisimple $k$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

> If $K / k$ is a finite seperable field extension and $L / k$ is some other field extension, show that $K \otimes_k L$ is a semisimple $k-algebra.

Since $K$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$, I know it's a free $k$-module. So $K \cong k^s$ for $s<\infty$. So I can write $K \otimes_k L \cong k^s \otimes L \cong L^s$. Wouldn't this imply that $K \otimes_k L$ is a semisimple $k$-algebra?

If this is not correct (which I doubt it is since I didn't use the seperability of K), could I be steered in the right direct please.

Comment: Bear this example in mind: if $K/k$ is a nontrivial finite purely inseparable field extension, then $K\otimes_k K$ has nilpotents, and so is not semisimple.

Comment: Your isomorphism is an isomorphism of modules, not algebras.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Darn. Thank you.

Comment: As you say, this argument can't be correct because it didn't use separability (and the result is false without separability). So you need to use separability somehow. What facts do you know about finite separable extensions? Can you prove this for any specific finite separable extensions, say quadratic ones?

Comment: Well, I know that implies that $K$ is a simple field extension, so $K=k(a)$. I'm not sure what to do after that.

Comment: So what do you think $k(a) \otimes_k L$ is? What do you know about how to compute tensor products?

Comment: Well I know that is isomorphic to $k[x]/(p(x)) \otimes_k L$, and I want to say that is isomorphic to $L[x]/(p(x))$, but I'm a little shaky on how to show that, and also, I'm not sure if this is a $k$-algebra isomorphism. So if $p(x)$ is also not reducible in $L$, I believe I would be done. If it is, then by the chinese remainder theorem I would have that it is isomorphic to $L[x]/(p_1(x)) \times \cdots \times L[x]/(p_k(x))$, which should tell me I have a semisimple $k$-algebra. But again, I'm not sure if this is a $k$-algebra isomorphism.

Comment: @user439126: yes, that's true, and yes, it is a $k$-algebra isomorphism. The general fact you want is that tensor products preserve colimits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the primitive element theorem, $K=k(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$.

If $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k$, then $k(\alpha)\cong k[x]/p(x)$. this is because the $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x]\to k(\alpha)$ given by evaluating polynomials at $\alpha$ is surjective with kernel $p(x)$; if any element of the kernel were not a multiple of $p(x)$, its remainder upon division by $p(x)$ would $\alpha$ as a root and smaller degree than $p(x)$, contra minimality.

Thus, $K\otimes_k L=k[x]/p(x)\otimes_k L$. This is isomorphic, as an algebra, to $L[x]/p(x)$. This is *extension of scalars* - a term usually used for modules, but applies here for algebras.

To see that there is an ismorphism (of $k$-algebras), first write down what the isomorphism is, see that it's invertible, and see that it preserves addition and multiplication.

Let's apply this with $k[x]\otimes L\cong L[x]$. The map $k[x]\otimes L\to L[x]$ is given by linearly extending the rule $x^n\otimes a\mapsto ax^n$, so that $p_1(x)\otimes a_1+\cdots+p_k(x)\otimes a_k\mapsto a_1p_1(x)+\cdots+a_kp_k(x)$. You simply turn the $\otimes$ symbol into actual multiplication in $L[x]$, since both $L$ and $k[x]$ are subalgebras! The inverse is given by $b_mx^m+\cdots+b_1x+b_0\mapsto x^m\otimes b_m+\cdots+x\otimes b_1+b_0$. Can you show this really is an inverse? (Remember you can slide scalars from $k$ across the $\otimes$ symbol, though not other scalars from $L$.) Can you show both maps are algebra homomorphisms?

The same applies with $k[x]/p(x)\otimes L\cong L[x]/p(x)$.

Now suppose $p(x)$ factors into irreducibles $p_1(x)\cdots p_r(x)$ over $L$. Note these factors must all be distinct, since otherwise $p(x)$ would have repeated roots in the algebraic closure of $k$ and then $K=k[x]/p(x)$ would not be separable, a contradiction. Therefore, the $p_i(x)$s are coprime and Chinese remainder theorem applies, which says $L[x]/p(x)\cong L[x]/p_1(x)\oplus \cdots L[x]/p_r(x)\cong L_1\oplus\cdots\oplus L_r$ which we can check is semisimple, i.e. has no nilpotent elements, given $L_i:=L[x]/p_i(x)$s are field extensions of $L$.

If you need help showing the explicit maps $k[x]\otimes L\leftrightarrow L[x]$ I gave are inverses of each other, or that they're algebra homomorphisms, or that the same applies to $k[x]/p(x)\otimes_k L\leftrightarrow L[x]/p(x)$, or how to show $\bigoplus L_i$ is semisimple, be sure to ask. Remember the trick to the homomorphism out of the tensor product is to turn $\otimes$ into plain-old multiplication, and the trick to the inverse is to separate out the $L$-coefficients using the $\otimes$ symbol - these are key to seeing why the maps are inverses and algebra homomorphisms.